# HTTPRequest to php not returning any values in firefox

Tags: javascript, php

I have a HTTPRequest that does not run using firefox, it does run on google chrome as it returns the alerts I have written for test.

```
var htpr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "../something.php";
  var val = "pro_ID="+prod_id+"&quan="+quan;
  alert("test ajx");
  htpr.open("POST", url, true);
  htpr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  htpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(htpr.readyState == 4 && htpr.status == 200){
        var dt = htpr.responseText;
        alert(dt);
    }
 }
 htpr.send(val);
}



if(isset($_POST['pro_ID'])) {       
    echo "Test";

}
echo "test wrong";
```

UPDATED problem found!

I found the error, as I have the ajax function to be triggered inside a html form I believe the default refresh function from the form was refreshing the page before the ajax was executed, I now set the form to prevent its defaults functions "event.preventDefault()". and it seems to have fixed. really weird! never thought that would be a problem

Comment: Any errors in the console (developers tool)?

Comment: @Ofir nope no errors at all, i cant figure it out why it wont work on firefox as its perfect fine on chrome.

Comment: Maybe a cache issue? (since it's a js code)

Answer (score 0):

Under:

```
htpr.onreadystatechange = function(){
```

add:

```
console.log(htpr);
```

Maybe it will show you why answer does not pass 'code 200, state 4' test.

You can also check 'Network' tab in Firefox. When XHR returns code 4xx or 5xx in Chrome, it shows in console information about it. In Firefox there is no information about XHR request problems - you got to check it in Network (request with problems are red).

Comment: I found the error, as I have the ajax function inside a <form> I believe the default refresh function from the form was refreshing the page before the ajax was executed, I now set the form to prevent its defaults functions "event.preventDefault()". and it seems to have fixed. really weird! never thought that would be a problem.